# ng-options is only working for name, not value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I've seen a few questions here similar to this. In fact that's how I got this far. But one little piece isn't working.  I have the following:

```
<select id="facility" class="form-control"
        ng-model="MainObj.facility" name="facility"
        ng-options="fclty.value as fclty.name for fclty in MainData.fclts"> 
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I've checked via logging that `MainData.fclts` contains exactly what I want, but each option outputs as

```
<option value="0" label="Actual Facility Name">Actual Facility Name</option>
<option value="1" label="Actual Facility Name">Actual Facility Name</option>
(etc)
```

In other words, it's putting the `name` in there correctly, but just using a `0, 1, 2, ...` for the value instead of what's in the value field.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Sample data:

```
[value: '00001', name: "John's House"]
[value: '00002', name: "School"]
[value: 'testval', name: "Testing Building"]
```

(etc)

EDIT 2:

Just for the fun of it, I swapped the two and did `fclty.name as fclty.value`. Sure enough the `value` showed up in the dropdown but the value portion of the `option` was still the default `0, 1, 2, ..`
So, it can SEE that field if it wants to, but, for some reason, doesn't want to use it to fill in the value of the `option`.

Comment: What are some sample contents of `MainData.fclts`?

Comment: I know. My issue is that it's seeing `fac.name` well enough to print it out, but not `fac.value` which is sitting right next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your MainObj and MainData look like? This example works exactly as it should:

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("main",["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.MainData = {
        fclts: [
          {name:"Place", value: "00001"},
          {name:"Other Place", value: "00002"},
          {name:"Thrid Place", value: "testval"}
        ]
    };
    $scope.MainObj = {facility: "00002"};
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="main">
    <select ng-model="MainObj.facility" name="facility" ng-options="fclty.value as fclty.name for fclty in MainData.fclts"> 
    </select>
    {{MainObj.facility}}
</body>
```

Your sample data is not in valid syntax, please confirm that they are formatted like objects:

```
[
  {value: "00001", name: "John's House"},
  {value: "00002", name: "School"},
  {name:"Thrid Place", value: "testval"}
]
```

Comment: I can't post the actual `MainObj` and `MainData` for confidentiality, but that's what they look like. I mean, it's seeing `fac.name` but somehow not seeing `fac.value` right next to it!

Comment: If your MainData object is formatted like mine is in my example, this will work. Please make sure that MainObj.fclts is an array with objects containing two properties: name and value, both strings. If that is not the case, you need to map your data into an array with such mentioned objects.

Comment: when I dump the array I get:
`(5) […]
​
0: Object { name: "Demo Data", value: "000001" }
​
1: Object { value: "000002", name: "Demo Data" }
​
2: Object { value: "000003", name: "Demo Data" }
​
3: Object { value: "000004", name: "Demo Data" }
​
4: Object { name: "Test One", value: "test-1" }
​
length: 5
​
<prototype>: Array []`

Comment: Obviously a tad altered for conf. but I didn't touch the structure

Comment: This answer is correct. Even though the value attribute in the optiontags are not the value you were expecting, the `ngModel` value is the same as the value of your objects. If that is not what you want, you should use the `ngOptions` directive on the options tag instead. Run the snippet and inspect the options attributes

Comment: I tried again and this time it's working! Thanks! I'm not sure why it wasn't doing it last time. I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

With **AngularJS V1.3**, the `ng-options` directive sets the value to the $index of the option.

```
<option value="" class=""></option>
<option value="0" label="John's House">John's House</option>
<option value="1" label="School">School</option>
<option value="2" label="Testing Building">Testing Building</option>
```

With **AngularJS V1.4,** the `ng-options` directive sets the value differently:

```
<option value="" class=""></option>
<option label="John's House" value="string:00001">John's House</option>
<option label="School" value="string:00002">School</option>
<option label="Testing Building" value="string:testval">Testing Building</option>
```

Between V1.3 and V1.4, the `ng-options` directive underwent major refactoring.

From the Docs:

> ### ngOptions
>
> The `ngOptions` directive has also been refactored and as a result some long-standing bugs have been fixed. The breaking changes are comparatively minor and should not affect most applications.
>
> Due to [7fda214c](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef), when `ngOptions` renders the option values within the DOM, the resulting HTML code is different. Normally this should not affect your application at all, however, if your code relies on inspecting the value property of `<option>` elements (that `ngOptions` generates) then be sure to read the details.
>
> Due to [7fda214c](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef), when iterating over an object's properties using the `(key, value) in obj` syntax the order of the elements used to be sorted alphabetically. This was an artificial attempt to create a deterministic ordering since browsers don't guarantee the order. But in practice this is not what people want and so this change iterates over properties in the order they are returned by `Object.keys(obj)`, which is almost always the order in which the properties were defined.
>
> Also due to [7fda214c](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef), setting the `ngOptions` attribute expression after the element is compiled, will no longer trigger the `ngOptions` behavior. This worked previously because the `ngOptions` logic was part of the `<select>` directive, while it is now implemented in the `ngOptions` directive itself.
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from V1.3 to V1.4 - ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngoptions)